# ¿Cómo se denomina en jerga técnica un sonido que no debió estar en una grabación?[¿Incidental?]

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, identificación-de-término

¿Cómo se dice en jerga técnica cuando en un video hay un sónido que no debió estar? Ya sea por alto, estridente, disonante, que se acople o sea fuera de lugar, por ejemplo antes de grabar dicen: Let's go!(a veces intencionalmente lo dejan) o murmullos, o por ejemplo en medio que se escuche alguien que se para de su asiento, se le cae un vaso o diga ¡Oh, me equivoqué! ¿Ruido, Sonido Incidental? ¿Accidental?¿Involuntario?¿Intrusivo?

Porque una cosa son los sonidos que se "cuelan" o "filtran" y otra cosa es la postproducción que es la edición para que lo que se grabó suene o quede registrado como uno quiere(incluso en un mismo momento se puede tocar de otra forma con los recursos que se tiene para que suene como se quiere), pero no es necesariamente un fallo y por el contrario música incidental o ambiental es la que acompaña, que está de fondo o que hacen los personajes en una obra y ésta última puede que desentone con la escena y por lo tanto hay que editar o minimizar.

---

Gracias por las respuestas, pero quiero saber: ¿Cómo se denomina en jerga técnica un sonido que no debió estar en una grabación y si incidental es incorrecto o sólo se aplica a la música que acompaña!

Answer (score 1):

#### Ruido de fondo

> Ruido procedente de todas las fuentes, tanto exterior como interior, que no se pueden identificar con claridad. También llamado ruido de ambiente, sonido de ambiente.

#### Ruido residual

> El ruido residual es el que permanece en un punto bajo ciertas condiciones, cuando el ruido de la fuente específica se suprime

Comment: El ruido residual es el del resto de las fuentes que afectan al específico. Pero por ejemplo en los programas de edición también se menciona al zumbido(sonido persistente de baja frecuencia) como distinto al ruido de fondo y opciones para reducir a cada uno. ¿Entonces consideras incidental incorrecto, un americanismo, una traducción o como música de fondo que acompaña y no con la connotación de ruido?

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, de la pregunta realizada y del comentario, se desprende la referencia a dos cosas distintas.

- 1.- Al sonido que se cuela en las grabaciones.
- 2.- La música ambiental que acompaña de fondo y el sonido de los personajes en una obra, sonidos que pueden desentonar con la escena.

Como ha señalado Danielillo, podemos encontrarnos con el ruido de fondo o ambiente y el ruido residual, una especie también de ruido ambiental sin un ruido específico, en donde se miden los niveles sonoros con la fuente funcionando y sin funcionar. Sin embargo, existen en general otros muchos ruidos que tienden a ser más específicos como son los zumbidos, ruidos de chasquidos tipo vinilo, los ruidos articulados por la voz, los ruidos de banda, producidos normalmente por el sofware, aquellos ruidos que son accidentales o esporádicos que recogen risas, caídas, golpes y portazos, estornudos... también el llamado ruido blanco, ideal para cubrir sonidos que provienen del exterior, como los sonidos de las motos, los coches, obras...

Así pues, si bien existen multitud de ruidos, lo cierto es que en la "jerga", para hacer referencia general a todos ellos, simplemente se dice "**ruido**" a no ser que queramos especificar a que tipo de denotación o "ruido" nos referimos, ya que "**ruido**" es todo sonido extraño a lo que queremos oír y registrar.

---

- Por otra parte **cuando nos referimos a los sonidos en el campo audiovisual**, la cuestión se encuentra muy estudiada, así se habla de sonido directo (el grabado durante el rodaje), sonido fuera de campo o diegético (un timbre que suena fuera del encuadre pero que oímos), **el sonido in** (aquél sonido o fuente situado en el interior del encuadre), **el sonido off** normalmente son los sonidos que se encuentran fuera del campo (puede ser la música de fondo y aquellos otros sonidos extradiegéticos, es decir, que no pertenecen a la acción de la escena y que también se pueden añadir posteriormente, efectos de sonido, de sala o sonido foley...). También podemos hallar el sonido "**wildtrack**" como aquel sonido, específico o para parchear, recogido independientemente de las imágenes para luego utilizarlo en postproducción.

Sea de una forma u otra, actualmente en la era digital, el tema de "**ruidos**", esta bastante avanzado y para estos "**ruidos o sonidos extraños**" existen numerosos filtros relacionados con el audio y sus distintas frecuencias, que permiten borrar, eliminar o atenuar las señales consideradas ajenas, restaurando las pista de audio a los niveles deseados, siendo en cualquier caso el "**ruido o sonido extraño**", sin especificar, **aquel agente ajeno y distinto al sonido que queremos percibir y grabar**.

Por tanto, si indicas este aspecto en una grabación puedes o no especificar.

**Sin especificar;**

- hay un ruido extraño en la pista.
- hay mucho ruido y no consigo quitarlo.
- ¿Qué hago con el ruido que aparece en el audio?.

**Especificando**;

- ¿Qué filtros puedo utilizar para evitar el *ruido del micrófono* ?
- La pista nº1 tiene problemas con *el ruido de articulación de la voz*.
- A veces aparecen un *zumbido* y también una especie de *ruido de vinilo*, que antes no estaban.